# Retrofit and SQlite how to remove lags

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I use Retrofit library for getting and parsing JSON from server.
All methods I run in MainActivity when Application is starting. And I have trouble when I check is Object(parsed from JSON) already exist in Data Base or not. Application is not responsing. What can I do?

here is MainActivity:

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MYFragmentListener, OnBackPressedListener  {

```
public static String FRAGMENT_INSTANCE_NAME = "";
public static String PACKAGE_NAME;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
DrawerAdapter listAdapter;


private Level level;


private String drawerlist[];
public static DrawerLayout drawer_layout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private int EXPAND_GROUP;
private int SELECTED_CHILD;
private int LANGUAGE_POSITION;


int height;

public AsanaPOJO [] asanasPOJO;

private List<String> listDataHeader;
private List<String> listData;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
private ExpandableListView expListView;
private ExpandableListView.LayoutParams expParam;
private LinearLayout expListLay;
private List<String> language;


private FragmentTransaction fTrans;
private FragmentManager fm;



private mainFragmentPh main_fragment_ph;
private StepOnePh step_one_ph;
private StepTwoPh step_two_ph;
private ProgramsVideoPh program_video_ph;
private ProgramOnePh program_one_ph;
private ProgramsPh programs_ph;
private AsanaOnePh asana_one_ph;
private AsanasPh asanas_ph;
private Finish2Ph finish2_ph;

private mainFragmentTb main_fragment_tb;
private ProgramAddTb program_add_tb;
private ProgramsVideoTb programs_video_tb;
private ProgramOneTb program_one_tb;
private ProgramsTb programs_tb;
private AsanaOneTb asana_one_tb;
private AsanasTb asanas_tb;
private Finish2Tb finish2_tb;
private AsanaInfoTb asana_info_tb;

Fragment fragment;


private Finish finish;
private add add_d;





boolean drawer_st;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    LANGUAGE_POSITION=-1;

    language = new ArrayList();
    final MYDBHelperFromApi DBHelperAPI = new MYDBHelperFromApi(this);


    MYapi myapi = (MYapi) new Builder().setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint(MYurl.BASE_URL).build().create(MYapi.class);
    myapi.getLanguages(new Callback<HashMap<String, String>>() {
        public void success(HashMap<String, String> hashMap, Response response) {
            language.addAll(hashMap.values());
            Log.d("LOGS", hashMap.toString() + " " + response.toString());
            DBHelperAPI.addLanguages(hashMap);
        }

        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d("LOGS", "FUUUUUUUUUUUU");
        }
    });
    myapi.getLevelList(new Callback<List<AsanaLevel>>() {
        public void success(List<AsanaLevel> asanaLevels, Response response) {
            for (AsanaLevel a : asanaLevels) {
                Log.d("LEVELASANA LOGS", BuildConfig.FLAVOR + a.toString());
            }
            DBHelperAPI.addAsanaLevel(asanaLevels);
        }

        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        }
    });
    myapi.getTypeList(new Callback<List<AsanaType>>() {
        public void success(List<AsanaType> asanaTypes, Response response) {
            for (AsanaType a : asanaTypes) {
                Log.d("TYPEASANA LOGS", BuildConfig.FLAVOR + a.toString());
            }
            DBHelperAPI.addAsanaType(asanaTypes);
        }

        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
    myapi.getProgramGoalList(new Callback<List<ProgramGoal>>() {
        public void success(List<ProgramGoal> programGoals, Response response) {
            for (ProgramGoal a : programGoals) {
                Log.d("GOALPROGRAM LOGS", BuildConfig.FLAVOR + a.toString());
            }
            DBHelperAPI.addProgramGoal(programGoals);
        }

        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        }
    });
    myapi.getProgramLevelList(new Callback<List<ProgramLevel>>() {
        public void success(List<ProgramLevel> programLevels, Response response) {
            for (ProgramLevel a : programLevels) {
                Log.d("LevelPROGRAM LOGS", BuildConfig.FLAVOR + a.toString());
            }
            DBHelperAPI.addProgramLevel(programLevels);
        }

        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        }
    });
    myapi.getAsanas(new Callback<Asanas>() {
        public void success(Asanas asanas,
                            Response response) {

            DBHelperAPI.addAsanas(asanas);
            List<Integer> listDB = DBHelperAPI.getAsanasIds();
            DBHelperAPI.checkForDeletedAsanas(asanas, listDB);
            for (AsanaPOJO a : asanas.getAsanas()) {
                Log.d("AsanaPROGRAM LOGS", BuildConfig.FLAVOR + a.getName());
            }
        }

        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d("FAILURE", "Failure");
        }
    });

    myapi.getPrograms(new Callback<Programs>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Programs programs, Response response) {
            DBHelperAPI.addPrograms(programs);
            for (ProgramPOJO p : programs.getPrograms()) {
                Log.d("PROGRAMs LOGS", BuildConfig.FLAVOR + p.getName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });


    expListLay =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.expListlay);



    ..................
```

}

and methods from DBhelper:

```
public void addPrograms(Programs programs){
open();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

for (ProgramPOJO p : programs.getPrograms()) {
    values.put(KEY_ID,p.getId());
    values.put(KEY_DURATION,p.getDuration());
    values.put(KEY_MAX_AGE,p.getMax_age());
    values.put(KEY_MIN_AGE,p.getMin_age());
    values.put(KEY_ISPAID,p.checkBool(p.getIs_paid()));
    values.put(KEY_IS_QUICK_RECEIPT,p.checkBool(p.getIs_quick_receipt()));
    values.put(KEY_BACKGROUND_SOUND_ID,p.getBackground_sound_id());
    values.put(KEY_IMGLARGE,p.getImgLarge());
    values.put(KEY_IMGTHUMB,p.getImgThumb());
    values.put(KEY_NAME,p.getName());
    values.put(KEY_GOAL_ID,p.getGoal_id());
    values.put(KEY_LEVEL_ID,p.getLevel_id());
    values.put(KEY_OLDPK,p.getOld_pk());
    if (checkById(TABLE_PROGRAMS, KEY_ID, p.getId())) {

        Log.d("LOGSPROGRAMOnly", " allready exist");

    } else {
        this.dbase.insert(TABLE_PROGRAMS, null, values);

        Log.d("LOGSPROGRAMOnly", p.getName() + " added");

    }
    for (Poses poses :p.getPoses()){
        ContentValues valuesForPose = new ContentValues();
        valuesForPose.put(KEY_ID,poses.getId());
        valuesForPose.put(KEY_POSITION,poses.getPosition());
        valuesForPose.put(KEY_DURATION,poses.getDuration());
        valuesForPose.put(KEY_VOICE,poses.getVoice());
        valuesForPose.put(KEY_ASANA_ID,poses.getAsana_id());
        valuesForPose.put(KEY_OLDPK,poses.getOld_pk());
        if (checkById(TABLE_POSES, KEY_ID, poses.getId())) {

            Log.d("LOGSPose", " allready exist");

        } else {
            this.dbase.insert(TABLE_POSES, null, valuesForPose);

            Log.d("LOGSPose", p.getName() + " added");


        }

        ContentValues valuesForPoseProgram = new ContentValues();
        valuesForPoseProgram.put(KEY_PROGRAM_ID, p.getId());
        valuesForPoseProgram.put(KEY_POSE_ID, poses.getId());
        if (checkPoseById(p.getId(), poses.getId())) {

            Log.d("LOGSPROGRAMPose", " allready exist");

        } else {
            this.dbase.insert(TABLE_POSES_PROGRAMS, null, valuesForPoseProgram);

            Log.d("LOGSPROGRAMPose", p.getName() + " added");


        }
    }
}

}

public void addAsanas(Asanas asanas) {
open();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
for (AsanaPOJO a : asanas.getAsanas()) {

    values.put(KEY_ID, Integer.valueOf(a.getId()));
    values.put(KEY_NAME, a.getName());
    values.put(KEY_IMGLARGE, a.getImgLarge());
    values.put(KEY_IMGTHUMB, a.getImgThumb());
    values.put(KEY_LEVELID, Integer.valueOf(a.getLevel_id()));
    values.put(KEY_TYPEID, Integer.valueOf(a.getType_id()));
    values.put(KEY_AUDIO, a.getAudio());
    values.put(KEY_TITLEAUDIO, a.getTitle_audio());
    values.put(KEY_DURATION, Integer.valueOf(a.getDuration()));
    values.put(KEY_SHORTDESC, a.getShortDesc());
    values.put(KEY_FULLDESC, a.getFullDesc());
    values.put(KEY_PHOTO, a.getPhoto());
    values.put(KEY_SANSKRITNAME, a.getSanskrit_name());
    values.put(KEY_SANSKRITAUDIOTITLE, a.getSanskrit_audio_title());
    values.put(KEY_BREATHINGVIDEO, a.getBreathing_video());
    values.put(KEY_ISBREATHING, Integer.valueOf(a.checkBool(a.getIs_breathing())));
    values.put(KEY_ISPAID, Integer.valueOf(a.checkBool(a.getIs_paid())));
    values.put(KEY_OLDIDENTIFIER, a.getName());
    values.put(KEY_OLDPK, a.getName());
    values.put(KEY_VIDEO, a.getVideo());
    if (checkById(TABLE_ASANAS, KEY_ID, a.getId())) {

        Log.d("LOGSASANA", " allready exist");

    } else {
        this.dbase.insert(TABLE_ASANAS, null, values);

        Log.d("LOGSASANA", a.getName() + " added");

    }


}
close();
}
public boolean checkById(String TableName, String dbfield, int id){
    Cursor cursor = this.dbase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " WHERE " + dbfield + " = " +  id , null);
    if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return true;

}
```

Comment: You have to add code of your `activity`. Your pieces of code say nothing about when and how they are called.

Comment: you should try to use Intent service or async task for multiple db operations at same time, because doing so causes lag as your main thread is doing too much work.

Answer (score 2):

what you have done is calling endpoint async-ly and processing the heavy db operation in main thread. 
You can do all these stuff in background thread using single AsyncTask.

Change your async retrofit endpoints to synchronous like:

```
void getPrograms(Callback<Programs>);
```

to

```
Programs myapi.getPrograms();
```

and a single async task like:

```
public class MyHeavyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final MYDBHelperFromApi DBHelperAPI;
    private final MYapi myapi;

    public MyHeavyTask(MYDBHelperFromApi DBHelperAPI, MYapi myapi) {
        this.DBHelperAPI = DBHelperAPI;
        this.myapi = myapi;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = myapi.getLanguages();
        boolean valid = hashMap != null;// do other validation catch exceptions if needed
        //Do response validation
        //Add to your database
        if (valid)
            DBHelperAPI.addLanguages(hashMap);

        //similarly
        List<AsanaLevel> asanaLevels = myapi.getLevelList();
        DBHelperAPI.addAsanaLevel(asanaLevels);

        List<AsanaType> asanaTypes = myapi.getTypeList();
        DBHelperAPI.addAsanaType(asanaTypes);

        List<ProgramGoal> programGoals = myapi.getProgramGoalList();
        DBHelperAPI.addProgramGoal(programGoals);

        //Similarly others

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now execute the task in onCreate method like:

```
new MyHeavyTask(DBHelperAPI,myapi).execute();
```